# Trying to access Oracle's Maven repository

Tags: oracle, maven, repository

I'm attempting to access Oracle's repository. Oracle doesn't make it easy. However, I'm attempting to follow [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9010) that Oracle provided.

I've:

- Approved [the licensing agreement](https://www.oracle.com/webapps/maven/register/license.html) on my system (in case there's some sort of cookie that needs to be set).
- Set both `M2_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` to `/usr/share/apache-maven`.
- Created an Oracle account.
- Added the Oracle Repository to my `settings.xml` file.
- Downloaded wagon-http 2.8 and put it in my `$M2_HOME/libs/ext` directory.
- Generated a master password and put it in `$HOME/.m2/settings-security.xml`
- Generated an encrypted password.
- Added the Oracle Maven Repository to my `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` file [as specified](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9014).
- Configured [HTTP Wagon](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9016) and added that to my `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` file.

My project POM looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.vegicorp</groupId>
    <artifactId>testMe</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testMe</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>wls-api</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My `settings.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <username>qazwart</username>
            <password>swordfish</password>
            <id>central</id>
        </server>
        <server>
            <username>qazwart</username>
            <password>swordfish</password>
            <id>snapshots</id>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
            <username>qazwart@foo.com</username>
            <password>{swordfish=}</password>
            <configuration>
                <basicAuthScope>
                    <host>ANY</host>
                    <port>ANY</port>
                    <realm>OAM 11g</realm>
                </basicAuthScope>
                <httpConfiguration>
                    <all>
                        <params>
                            <property>
                                <name>http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects</name>
                                <value>%b,true</value>
                            </property>
                        </params>
                    </all>
                </httpConfiguration>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>libs-release</name>
                    <url>http://repo.vegicorp.net/artifactory/libs-release</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots />
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                    <url>http://repo.vegicorp.net/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
                    <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>plugins-release</name>
                    <url>http://repo.vegicorp.net/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <snapshots />
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
                    <url>http://repo.vegicorp.net/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            <id>artifactory</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

When I run Maven, I get this:

```
$ mvn clean package                                                                            
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testMe 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://maven.oracle.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
Downloading: http://repo.vegicorp.net/artifactory/libs-release/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.vegicorp.net/artifactory/libs-release/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom (10 KB at 69.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://maven.oracle.com/com/oracle/wls-api/12.1.2/wls-api-12.1.2.pom
Downloading: http://repo.vegicorp.net/artifactory/libs-release/com/oracle/wls-api/12.1.2/wls-api-12.1.2.pom
Downloading: http://repo.vegicorp.net/artifactory/libs-snapshot/com/oracle/wls-api/12.1.2/wls-api-12.1.2.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.787 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-15T16:37:56-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/156M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project testMe: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.vegicorp:testMe:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.oracle:wls-api:jar:12.1.2: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.oracle:wls-api:jar:12.1.2: Could not transfer artifact com.oracle:wls-api:pom:12.1.2 from/to maven.oracle.com (https://maven.oracle.com): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

It appears that I don't have access to the Oracle repository although I accepted the licensing agreement and am using the account I've created. Is there something I'm missing? If I remove the reference to wls-api.jar in my `pom.xml`, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `settings.xml` I can see that you use Artifactory. Why won't you define Oracle's repository as a remote in Artifactory? That will make the access much easier. [Here's a simple guide on how to do so](http://buttso.blogspot.com.au/2015/02/fronting-oracle-maven-repository-with.html).

And, of course, [here's the official user guide on it](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-UsingOracleMavenRepository).

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: I tried getting Artifactory and Oracle's repo to work, but couldn't. There are no directions for getting the repo to work with Artifactory. So, I've just tried following the directions Oracle gave, but still can't get it to work. If you have any info on getting Artifactory and Oracle's Maven repo to work, let me know. I'd prefer having Artifactory handle it rather than having to tell my development team they have to configure their `.settings.xml` file a particular way.

Comment: What do you mean "there are no directions"? I just gave you a link to a very detailed blog post on how to do it. Plus, you can (and should) always look in the official user guide, [it has this information as well](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-UsingOracleMavenRepository).

Comment: For some reason I missed your reference to the blog pos (and the official directions)t. I looked at the blog post, and I had pretty much setup everything as specified. The only difference is that I then checked _hard fail_ (which wasn't set before) to see if that gave me any info. I use Artifactory 3.7.0. I checked out the _weblogic-with-arquillian_ project to test (as stated by the blog post). This time, everything worked. So, I didn't change anything I had before in Artifactory, but it now works.

Comment: It's worth mentioning here that Oracle's becoming a bit notorious lately for not having their act 100% squared away when it comes to POMs. It's almost always a good idea to maintain your own mirror if you support more a team of developers.  See: http://www.munzandmore.com/2017/ora/osb-12-2-1-2-issues-maven-solution

Answer (score 1):

For anybody that has spent any time fighting with this ... make sure that the ID of the oracle repository in your POM is the same as the ID of the server defined in your Settings.xml.

This is not documented anywhere but it appears that maven just does not request authorization if these IDs do not match. It does not attempt it based upon the URL as other solutions appear to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed accepting the Oracle Maven repository terms and conditions. https://www.oracle.com/webapps/maven/register/license.html